# Logging in after an Acronis Restore on Server 2003 with "Windows Cannot Connect to Domain..." msg

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, domain-controller

We have two machines both running Windows Server 2003. The AD Machine is the Active Directory. The CTX Machine is our Citrix File Server (this has a RAID Array).

Recently we had a RAID problem and used Acronis 2016 to restore the machine after repairing the RAID array.

In addition we moved the machines to a new location with a different IP set-up
We can log in locally to both machines and have changed the fixed IP addresses so that they can ping.  We also changed the DNS address on the CTX machine so it can browse.

So we know all that is working BUT
When someone tries to log in remotely either locally or from outside we get:

> Windows cannot connect to the domain, either because the domain
>   controller is down or otherwise unavailable, or because your computer
>   account was not found. Please try again later. If this message
>   continues to appear, contact your System Administrator for assistance.

We are worried about using freeware, we tried one or two solutions found on the net but they ended up blocking the whole thing and so we have just re-restored the o/s.  We believe it has something to do with the passwords on the AD machine losing synchronisation with the local passwords on the CTX machine.

Comment: Can you add more detail about the IP change to your question?  This may be the source of your problem.

Comment: This question is a hot mess. Did you restore on or two machines? Did you restore your DC from a backup? How many DC's do you have? You also assigned new ip addresses and moved the machines? You used freeware software to do what exactly? Please rephrase your question into something more logical and detailed so we can make sense of it.

Comment: Hi thanks for yr comments.  To answer pat o first: the previous scheme was 10.10.10.xxx but since the move the current scheme is 10.10.100.xxx

Comment: to answer joeqwerty: after move all we did was change the fixed IP on the AD machine & add new gateway IP  On CTX we changed the fixed IP & defined DNS as IP address of the AD machine.  All worked fine local/remote login etc.  RAID (CTX) showing red light & on format/rebuild Raid failed.  We created a new configuration with 3 spare disks & restored the CTX machine only. Altho local login OK remote not poss. That's when we posted. Now restoring BOTH the AD & the CTX machines to have initial situation before RAID failure.  Hope this is clearer! Jean